# Trying to get the value of an element in a single linked list

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list

I am writing my own single linked list for learning purposes, but I stuck at the "Get" Method.

```
public void Get(int index)
{
  SLElement curr = _root;
  SLElement prev = _root._next;
  for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
  {
    while (curr._next != null)
    {
      if (curr == null) return;
      prev = curr; 
      curr = curr._next;
    }
  }
  prev._next = curr._next;
  curr._next = prev;
  Console.WriteLine("Index {0} has the value {1}", index, curr._value);
}
```

It seems to work, but when I want to know the value of the last element in the list, it gives me a `NullReferenceException`
 Any way to prevent this?

Comment: `index - 1` is your max item

Comment: Read this nice series of articles on Assymetric Bounds from Dr.Dobb's Magazine http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/asymmetric-bounds-part-1-what-are-they/240001666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it starts at 0, your `for()` loop should stop when `i = index - 1` (ie `i < index`) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
```

The first element is at position 0, so the last one is at position `index - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this now:

```
public void Get(int index)
{
  SLElement curr = _root;
  SLElement prev = _root._next;
  for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
  {
    while (curr._next != null)
    {
      if (curr == null) return;
      prev = curr; 
      curr = curr._next;
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Index {0} has the value {1}", index, curr._value);
  if (prev == null) return;
  prev._next = curr._next;
  curr._next = _root;
}
```

This works for me